# Setting custom user object in context processor in django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I have a custom user model. After doing successful login, I am getting the anonymous user in HttpResponseRedirect and templates as well. How do I get the logged in user?

Login View:

```
class LoginFormView(View):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    user_model = get_user_model()
    template_name = 'account/login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please enter correct email and password!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Comment: I think you might be importing the wrong `login`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) enabled, you'll be able to access the user in the template with `{{ request.user}}`.

Secondly, make sure you are importing the login **function** and not the login **view**. It should be:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

Comment: 'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
I have specified. Code snippet above.

Comment: I can't see the problem in your view. I would consider using Django's [built in login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) instead of writing your own.

Comment: I am using inbuilt login function only. Also using debugger, I have checked that it works fine and logins successfully.

Comment: Yes, you are using the login function but you are not using the login **view**. You don't have to use it, it's just a suggestion since your current set up isn't working.